# Calling a C# (.NET) Method from PowerBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, powerbuilder

I am looking for direction in regards to calling a C# module 
(written in the .NET (2.1) framework) from PowerBuilder.  Here is the C#.NET 
information: The function is used to connect to COM PORT device and get the device status.

```
NameSpace:  NETS
Class:    NETS
Method:    REQUESTCARDSTATUS()
DLL:    NETS.dll
```

Using my dll as OLE Object in Powerbuilder.**I am using PowerBuilder version 11.5. I have a simple window with a command button on it.  Within this window, my code looks like this:**

`OLEObject ole_3`
`ole_3 = CREATE OLEObject`

// connect to C# class
`MessageBox("Value = ", +String(li_rc))`
`IF li_rc <> 0 THEN` 
    `DESTROY ole_3`
`END IF`

```
 li_sum = ole_3.RequestCardStatus();
```

**Getting error while calling this function Error R0035: Error Calling External Function.**

The function is working fine when try to call the function using c# application. I don't know what is causing the issue in powerbuilder. Trying from past three day, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you have not called the *ConnectToNewObject* function for starting the Ole server application. After creating ole_3 and before calling the RequestCardStatus function, you should call this function as follows:

> ole_3.ConnectToNewObject ( classname )

where classname is a Progid or a Classid of the server

Comment: That line was erased by me during editing. I have called the function "ConnectToNewObject". Also that functions return '0'. But the error comes while calling the function ole_3.RequestCardStatus();

Comment: @Apurva Have you registered the module on your system?

Comment: Yes registered the module using regasm utility.

Answer (score 0):

The C# dll must be made COM visible.

The syntax to connect (using your example) would be:  ole_3.ConnectToNewObject('NETS.NETS')